# Is there a name for the "kernel principle"?

Tags: distributions, normalization

In many cases, we do not actually have to explicitly compute the normalization constant of a certain distribution, if we know its kernel and it corresponds to a known family.

Is there a name for this "trick" that I can look up and read more about? I don't think there is something very deep about it, but I figured it must be carrying some name.

Thanks.

Comment: all probability measures assign measure one to the entire sample space (by definition). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: well, that is the reason this trick holds. I thought it might have a name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was taught the stock phrase "recognising the density of a *whatever* distribution," to use as part of a mathematical proof. I agree this 'trick' is useful, but AFAIK it doesn't have a name.

Comment: I guess it does not have a name. thanks.